# Changing the LSMinimumSystemVersion in Catalyst

Tags: ios, macos, info.plist, mac-catalyst

I have an app with a minimum version requirement of macOS 10.15.2 in a Catalyst project.

If I try to add LSMinimumSystemVersion to the info.plist, I'm not able to upload the app as an iOS app (for some reason, it gets treated as a Mac app in that case, just by being there.)

Is there another way to set the minimum version? Or do I just need to add it when archiving the Mac app and remove it when archiving the iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the app target Build Settings tab and search for "macOS Deployment Target". Use the drop-down menu to select "Other" and enter your desired deployment target number. In this case 10.15.2.